# Localhost auth for LangChain Google Drive loader

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, langchain

I am trying to use the [Google Drive document loader](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/indexes/document_loaders/examples/google_drive.html) from LangChain and I'm getting stuck at the OAuth stage. I am using Google Colab and here is the code:

```
loader = GoogleDriveLoader(
    folder_id="1ABCD_hmqMW7U6H66J0LDM3Irl9999999",
    credentials_path="/content/sample_data/credentials.json",
    recursive=False
)

docs = loader.load()
```

This code will generate an authorization URL in this format (each parameter is separated by a line break for improved readability):

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
response_type=code&
client_id=1234567891-2ksrji4mcgmq62audjsgrat0l62abcde.apps.googleusercontent.com&
redirect_uri=http://localhost:53439/&
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly&
state=bzpi3mGUZMvbBpBsM4X7d6nuV6keqF&
access_type=offline
```

When I click the authorization link it correctly identifies my app, choose an account to continue, and then correctly asks whether I trust the app. After confirming that I do indeed trust my own app, I receive an error saying, "**This site can’t be reached**.
localhost refused to connect."  This is the URL:

http://localhost:53439/?state=bzpi3mGUZMvbBpBsM4X7d6nuV6keqF&code=4/0AbUR2VPSPZlKGd8czpH-LjCsaaM5JkW0vp5QqF_SI7_bfUuD8Px7a_XNHOrESrSLsCDblA&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

and here it is again with each parameter on a separate line:

```
URL: http://localhost:53439/
state: bzpi3mGUZMvbBpBsM4X7d6nuV6keqF
code: 4/0AbUR2VPSPZlKGd8czpH-LjCsaaM5JkW0vp5QqF_SI7_bfUuD8Px7a_XNHOrESrSLsCDblA
scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
```

What am I doing wrong?  What do I need to do to authenticate my app?

Comment: You have received the authorization code in the query parameter - `code`, use this to get the access token.

Comment: For the error, check the local server if it serves a file at that address.

Comment: Thanks @ArpitJain, what should I do with the access token that is received in the URL `code` ?

Comment: No, you need to exchange this authorization code for an access token.

Comment: Please look at here:- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code

Comment: Are you doing it from your local machine or a VM on cloud? In the latter case make sure you forward the port in the URL (53439 in this case) to your local machine where you open that link